# Prevent Google from indexing iframes while allowing indexing iframe content embedded in other pages

Tags: seo, google-search, iframe

Let's assume there's an HTML page hosted on `http://programmer-domain.example/iframe.html`, containing text "SDFHIASDFASDFKSDAF".

Let's assume there's also another page, `http://customer-domain.example/index.html`, that includes this first page via an iframe tag.

As it's known, Google indexing engine indexes the iframes in a way if you google for "SDFHIASDFASDFKSDAF", both pages will be shown in results.

How can this be achieved that only the page in `customer-domain.example` is indexed, but not the `programmer-domain.example` one? I guess using noindex in HTML tags of `iframe.html`, or Disallow-ing in `robots.txt` of `programmer-domain.example` will result in no pages being indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set a canonical tag to your parent document. Add the following to the head of your iframe:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://your-parent-document" />
```

This is a signal to search engines that your parent doc is the preferred resource.

These questions might be of interest for you:

- [Can canonical links and noindex be used with iframes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/105946/29551)
- [Google Ignoring Canonical - Asking for Advice on Alternative Option](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/106406/29551)